# Where is the user crontab stored?

Tags: cron

Since upgrading my user's crontab has been wiped out. This is not the first time this has happened this year and it's a pain restoring it each time.

I'd like to be able to back up the crontab for my user but for that I need to know where it's stored.

Comment: it would be nice if someone could also give a reason WHY it's wiped out

Comment: @WalterTross Yeah it's quite annoying. I would guess it's a side-effect of updating the `cron` package but I agree - it's not something that should happen.

Comment: Uh, I don't that user cron's get wiped per cron package upgrade!

Comment: @pl1nk I've no idea what's wiping it out but it does keep happening. Ghost in the machine, I guess.

Comment: User tables are stored on a temporary area 
/var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USER, as such the may be deleted on your next boot or upgrading.

Comment: Just want to mention that there are instructions here about how to reconstruct an accidentally deleted crontab using logs:  http://superuser.com/questions/384109/crontab-deleted  It's not really what you were asking but it might be of use to someone.

Answer (score 444, accepted):

Actually, it's not recommended to handle those files by hand. Per `crontab` man page:

> Each  user  can  have their    own    crontab,    and    though
>   these    are    files   in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`,  they are not
>   intended to be edited directly.

Files under `/var/spool` are considered temporary/working, that's why they probably get deleted during an upgrade, though a closer look at the `cron` package's upgrade scripts may shed some light on this.

Anyway, it's always a good practice to back up your cron entries or keep them in a file in your home directory.

I assume you're using `crontab -e` to create crontab files on the fly. If so, you can get a "copy" of your crontab file by doing `crontab -l`. Pipe that to a file to get a "backup":

```
crontab -l > my-crontab
```

Then you can edit that my-crontab file to add or modify entries, and then "install" it by giving it to crontab:

```
crontab my-crontab
```

This does the same syntax checking as `crontab -e`.

Comment: `crontab -l` is easier than going through `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USER` mostly because of the bizarre permissions on that file.

Comment: The `iptables-save` of cron. Nice...

Comment: if you use your root account for crontab, then its sudo crontab -l > root-crontab for roots crontab!

Comment: Perhaps we should put a crontab to automatically back itself up >:)?

Comment: Poking through `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` is handy when you want to curate or examine crontabs from multiple users.

Comment: "Files under /var/spool are considered temporary/working" while true they can still contain important data (for example mail that is yet to be sent), so they shouldn't just be cleared out arbiterally.

Comment: When investigating mysteries on a server you aren't familiar with, it is common to `sudo grep -rHin "$string" /etc/cron*` (where string might be a command like `docker`, `lftp`, `iptables`, etc. It's a good idea to check user crontabs also. That's what lead me to this Q&A. `sudo grep -rHin "$string" /etc/cron* /var/spool/cron*`

Answer (score 68):

Its stored inside `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` folder under username.

Comment: Thanks, I realize this is an old answer. It's at `var/spool/cron/tabs/<user>` on a recent OpenSuse Tumbleweed installation.

Answer (score 36):

I finally found out *why* my crontabs and Postfix installation kept breaking after boot. It's a really stupid reason but...

I had `/var/spool` mounted as a `tmpfs` RAM-drive.

Sounds idiotic and it is, but I had followed one of the old SSD-tweaks to lengthen the life of my SSD. In doing so, I blindly mounted `/tmp`, `/var/tmp` and `/var/spool` as `tmpfs` without thinking of the repercussions. I thought `/var/spool` was like `/proc/` or `/run/` and that it was only useful for the duration of the session. I was clearly wrong.

Comment: It should be safe to mount `/tmp` as tmpfs, but not `/var/tmp` or `/var/spool`.  `/tmp` is used for temporary storage that may be lost upon reboot.  `/var/tmp` is used for temporary storage that will remain after a reboot.  And as you've discovered, `/var/spool` is for data to be processed, which will also remain after a reboot.

Comment: See http://www.pathname.com/fhs/2.2/fhs-5.15.html

Comment: Note also that write count is no longer an issue with modern SSDs.

Answer (score 20):

To list all cron jobs from all users in your system:

```bsh
for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd)
do
  echo $user
  crontab -u $user -l
done
```

An alternative to your issue would be to place them in cron.d folder and specify the appropriate user per cron as in example:

```
00 01 * * * user /home/user/user-script.sh
```

Comment: if you're recovering the crontab from another drive, this will not work because `crontab -u` is running from your current system.

Comment: While I suppose that is a one-liner in that it fits in less than 80 characters and is somewhat readable, I generally like to put code in a format such that a person can either copy-paste or put it in a script (and, in a script, this would **not** be one line of code). Suggesting edit...

Comment: Also, I was about to turn it into a `while read user` loop, to handle the case where the username contains spaces, but apparently that's not an issue. Very limited set of username characters.