# Can I restore content of /var/spool for package defaults?

Tags: package-management

I'm a Class A Muppet. I have had [`/var/spool/` mounted as `tmpfs`](https://askubuntu.com/a/302006/449) for over a year and that means crontab has never been able to remember what it's doing and postfix has been broken.

I'm not asking to restore lost data. That data is long gone.

I would like to restore the *default* content of `/var/spool/` though. `crontab` seems to manage to write its own but to get `postfix` back online I have to reconfigure (or reinstall) it. These are just two systems that I know of. There could be dozens more.

Is there any way to tick through all the installed packages and work out which should have something in `/var/spool/`? And by extension, is there any simple way to restore that data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you've unmounted, and got rid of the configuration to mount `/var/spool` as `tmpfs` by removing it from `/etc/fstab`, you can run the following commands to reinstall all the packages which own files in `/var/spool`:

`dpkg -S /var/spool | sed 's/\:.*$//;s/,//g' | xargs sudo apt-get install --reinstall`

The `dpkg -S` command lists all of the packages which own `/var/spool` or something under it. The pipe to `sed` strips off the end and then removes the commas from the comma-and-space-separated list of package names. And finally the `xargs` is to pass the list of packages on to `sudo apt-get install --reinstall` as the list of arguments, rather than the normal `STDIN` that a pipe sends to.

Comment: Might even be cleaner as `sudo apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg -S /var/spool | sed 's/,//g;s/\:.*$//')` but I'm going to stop messing around with it for now!