# How to set up a root cron job properly

Tags: cron

I tried to set up a root cron job to run a Bash script as root, to run at minute 7,37, every hour, every day of month, every month. This script is located in `/usr/bin` and named `tunlrupdate.sh`. It updates the DNS of Tunlr.

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/tunlrupdate.sh 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2133 Sep 24 15:42 /usr/bin/tunlrupdate.sh
```

This Bash script is available [here](https://github.com/JochenB/tunlrupdate/blob/master/tunlrupdate.sh).

When invoked the script writes what's happening in a log located in `/var/log/tunlr.log`

To add this root cron job I used the standard for root's crontab

```
sudo crontab -e
```

And inserted these 2 lines at the end. I expect cron to run the script as root.

```
# check for updated Tunlr DNS every 30 minutes at the hour + 7 mn and hour + 37 mn
07,37 * * * * root /usr/bin/tunlrupdate.sh
```

A later command `sudo crontab -l` confirmed that the cron job has been inserted.

I did reboot Ubuntu and was checking in the log file if the cron job was launched properly. However there is nothing in the logfile `/var/log/tunlr.log` meaning the job was never successfully launched.

I did check that if I run the script from the command line

```
sudo /usr/bin/tunlrupdate.sh
```

then the logfile is updated accordingly.

Why is this cron job not running as planned in my system?

UPDATE 1 : All the proposed solutions so far do not work. I thank Olli for a CLI to list the system log `sudo grep CRON /var/log/syslog`. However I did get a CRON error

```
CRON[13092]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ]
&& find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php
/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
```

with the suggested PATH= insertion & use of absolute path from root for functions in the script or without this suggested solutions here. I still get this error.

After some searching I pinpointed the error in the file `/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime` as is explained [here](https://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?t=9780&p=55980): `Change #!/bin/sh -e --> #!/bin/sh -x`

Then listing the CRON error log in my system

```
sudo grep CRON /var/log/syslog
Feb 11 18:07:01 Marius-PC CRON[14067]: (root) CMD (root /usr/bin/tunlrupdate.sh)
Feb 11 18:07:01 Marius-PC CRON[14066]: (root) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got
status 0x00ff, #012)
```

I still don't get the bash script executing. This time no error is shown in the log. To get assurance this was not the content of the script I reduced the script to the following 3 lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
LOGFILE=/var/log/tunlr.log
echo $LOGFILE >> $LOGFILE
```

I still don't get the cron job through. Nothing is written in the log file. So even may be an empty script will not run in cron ? I don't get it. I am know trying a script reduced to these 2 lines:

```
#!/bin/bash
exit 0
```

And still the same error log. The cron script does not go through ...

Comment: If you want it to bee a "root" cronjob you have to be root then you type crontab -e. Also you just have to login as root (console type "su root") and then crontab -e (sudo is not needed in this case).

Comment: Well. I don't see the point of your answer ? Typing $ sudo crontab -e did the job as reported by $ sudo crontab -l , i.e. the line describing the new job has been added to the root's cron. As per se the job is not present in the user cron e.g. $ crontab -l do not show any cron job was added here.

Comment: @WolfgangVogl he used "sudo" which works as expected.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, at last the working solution. In the syslog I saw the repetitive and intriguing:

```
CRON[18770]: (root) CMD (root /usr/bin/tunlrupdate.sh)
```

That sounds like root was not recognized as a cmd. As I already used the root's cron by using `$ sudo /usr/bin/tunlrupdate.sh`. Then I tried with the original script (corrected for a mistake in the date UNIX cmd : %m which is month was used for minutes which is %M) the following (which removes the root from the cron line):

```
$ sudo crontab -e
# check for updated Tunlr DNS every 30 minutes at the hour + 7 mn and hour + 37 mn
07,37 * * * * /usr/bin/tunlrupdate.sh
```

This turned out to be the final solution. [Although I found scores of literature stating the erroneous line with root in the cron line. That was a mistake].

Comment: Good point Olli. I agree with you on that. For reference the user crontab is stored in /var/spool/cron/crontabs/user-name or for root /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root . See this page http://askubuntu.com/questions/216692/where-is-the-user-crontab-stored The containing folder already is and gives the name of the user.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't need that information, as you only should edit crontab files with `crontab` command (except crontab files under `/etc`).

Comment: @Antonio the scores with the username field are only used in `/etc/crontab` (the system-wide crontab). Using `sudo crontab -e` you're working with root's crontab which usually can be found in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`

Answer (score 106):

If you want to run a script as a **normal user**:

```
crontab -e
```

And add the line:

```
07,37 * * * * /usr/bin/tunlrupdate.sh
```

If you want to run your script as **root**:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

And add the same line:

```
07,37 * * * * /usr/bin/tunlrupdate.sh
```

Comment: @NineCattoRules If you don't drop the output, what do you see?

Comment: @AngeloFuchs old comment...surely I tried that command as root (`sudo crontab -e` instead of `crontab -e`). Or something else, anyway it works

Comment: But the crontab file will be in a temporary file? Or I am missing an automatic copy? Because the file edited with `sudo crontab -e` is clearly in /tmp

Answer (score 5):

One "problem" with cron is that lack of environment variables (for *obvious* security reasons). You are probably missing PATH and HOME. You can define those in the script directly or in the crontab file.

```
# check for updated Tunlr DNS every 30 minutes at the hour + 7 mn and hour + 37 mn
PATH=/usr/bin
07,37 * * * * root /usr/bin/tunlrupdate.sh
```

You'll have to test until all the necessary variables are defined as required by the script.

Comment: This is the only answer here that actually worked for me.  I copied the SHELL and PATH statements from the `/etc/crontab` file and pasted them into the `sudo crontab -e` and the command ran as root without a problem.  Thank you!

Comment: yes! That was most likely the issue with my own cron issues :) thanks a lot!

Comment: What are these obvious security reasons? What risks do I take by adding the `PATH` variable to my root crontab?

Comment: @Joooeey When you define your own variables, it is considered safe. By default, CRON offers no environment variables to make it safer. Many people think that they would get the same variable as found in their usual shell. There could be passwords or keys or some other secret in those variables and CRON doesn't want to leak them to your CRON jobs.

Answer (score 2):

Cron error messages are usually - by default - sent via email. You can check whether there's email for root with `sudo mail`, or by just checking contents of `/var/mail/root`, e.g `sudo less /var/mail/root`.

---

If email messages does not help, also check `/var/log/syslog`:

```
sudo grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

---

As Alexis Wilke already said, cron have different mechanism for setting environment variables.

Your script needs

```
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

to the crontab. `HOME` shouldn't be necessary. You should use absolute paths in your scripts, e.g `/bin/date` instead of `date`. You can find proper paths for each command with  `which command_name`, e.g

```
$ which date
/bin/date
```

Comment: Running your suggested grep CRON in /var/log/syslog I got the foolowing

Feb 11 14:37:01 Marius-PC CRON[7826]: (root) CMD (root /usr/bin/tunlrupdate.sh)

Feb 11 14:37:01 Marius-PC CRON[7825]: (root) MAIL (mailed 1 byte of output; but got status 0x00ff, #012)

Feb 11 14:39:01 Marius-PC CRON[7849]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)
If I add some definitiion for the PATH in cron these will not affect my system $PATH ?

Comment: That output says it tried to email something but failed. That means, you are not getting that error message to `/var/mail/root`. You can either fix that, or try with `PATH=...`

Comment: @Antonio, alternatively, use this [patched version](https://github.com/ojarva/tunlrupdate/blob/master/tunlrupdate.sh)

Comment: Thanks. I know I didn't configure system e-mail and was aware that didn't go through. I already had modified the script to use absolute path for any function called. The last thing was my previous question a PATH definition within crontab will not mess my system $PATH variable ?

Comment: No it doesn't. That's completely separate thing.

Comment: In the mean time I was busy correcting a bug in the date format from the original script. It was using %m (which is for month NOT minute) instead of %M ...

Comment: After modifying the script and adding the PATH= I still get the same error 
(root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete)

Comment: That's not an error. It's a different cron job, namely, php cleanup. It is not related to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line in your script. So after you check the cron logs and comprove your job was executed you can get the the same $PATH of crontabs had.

```
/bin/echo $PATH > /root/path.txt
```

And probably the best thing you can do to diagnose issues in cron scripts is get all the environment variables of SO with env command in your script. So just add this line to your script. Then you can analyze the output `allEvnVars.txt`

```
/usr/bin/env > /root/allEvnVars.txt
```

Another trick is to direct the output of the script to some place. Adding the `/root/log.log`. This way all the output of the script will be maintained in `/root/log.log`

```
07,37 * * * * root /usr/bin/tunlrupdate.sh  > /root/log.log
```

Also you can schedule the script to run each min to facilitate the tests and checks.

```
*/1 * * * * root /usr/bin/tunlrupdate.sh  > /root/log.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You state in your question that you reduced the script to:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
LOGFILE=/var/log/tunlr.log
echo $LOGFILE >> $LOGFILE
```

I have had problems with this before. It turned out to be the first line. Instead of `#!/bin/bash` I tried `#!/bin/sh` and that worked (for me, at least).

Comment: This might have been because the `bash` interpreter was in a different location. Use `which bash` to find out where `bash` lives, and use that path in your shebang.