# Run "sudo service udev reload" without root priviledges

Tags: 12.04, sudo, services, udev

I have a script that occasionally needs to run the command "service udev reload" but cannot as it needs root access. I don't want to stay logged in as root all the time, so I'm wondering if there is a way to change permissions for this command.

I'm on 12.04.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Setup a root cron Job Properly](http://askubuntu.com/questions/419548/how-to-setup-a-root-cron-job-properly)

Answer (score 0):

From the man page: `sudo` allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or another user, as specified by the security policy.

So, this is the proper way to restart a service:

```
sudo service udev reload
```

if you do not want to do it by hand, you can always add an entry in crontab to execute the command at time intervals

Comment: Just to check, this would have to be in the `/etc/cron.hourly` or `/etc/cron.daily` (or related variants) folders, right?

Comment: yes, adding a script in those directories, or edit crontab with `sudo crontab -e` and add a line with command/script putting the date and time you want. Refer to `man crontab` for more help.

Comment: I don't really know the answer to OP's question, but I think this is missing the point. I think he already has a script that runs `sudo service udev reload`, but he wants to be able to run that specific command without `sudo` and still have it work.