# Crontab script not running (16.04)

Tags: bash, scripts, cron

First- I've already scoured [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working#) and nothing has worked.

My script will create a file, this is how I know if it has run or not. `/var/log/syslog` isn't giving me any debugging information. Below is my crontab section, below what's already there by default:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

# Check for minecraft server updates
* * * * * root minecraft_update > /tmp/cron.out

# TEST
* * * * * root env > /tmp/env.out
```

Note: there is a blank line at the end of the crontab file. I specified the bash shell even though that is specified in my script. My script (`minecraft_update`) lives in the `/usr/local/bin` directory, and the only other commands it calls are `grep`, `ls`, and `head`, which are all in the `/bin` dir, which is already defined in the crontab PATH.

The `/tmp/cron.out` file is created, but empty. The `/tmp/env.out` file is created and confirms that the PATH includes both the `/usr/local/bin` and `/bin` dirs, and also confirms the `SHELL=/bin/bash`.

Addtl. perms info:

```
ll /etc/crontab
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 998 Jul  1 12:47 /etc/crontab

ll /usr/local/bin/minecraft_update
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 1132 Jul  1 12:31 minecraft_update*
```

I'm so frustrated with this! Please bring an end to my * * * * * misery... [That's cron notation, not profanity btw. Gotta love Linux humor :)]

Comment: I'd start by redirecting standard error to the file as well (i.e. `minecraft_update > /tmp/cron.out 2>&1`) - that might give you some indication of what's failing

Comment: It's still empty...

Comment: Your problem seems to be with the minecraft_update script, not cron nor crontab.

Comment: But I can run the script just fine and it runs as expected.

Comment: Are you editing `/etc/crontab` directly, or are you using `sudo crontab -e`? (Which uses a different file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You don't need 'root' in the crontab listing, (unless you have a program `root` that you are using to run your script).</s>

If ypu are editing your crontab with `sudo crontab -e` (/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root), then you do not need a username. If you are editing the system-wide crontab (/etc/crontab), then you do need a username listed.

E.x.

`sudo crontab -e`

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

# Check for minecraft server updates
* * * * * minecraft_update > /tmp/cron.out

# TEST
* * * * * env > /tmp/env.out
```

OR `nano /etc/crontab`

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

# Check for minecraft server updates
* * * * * root minecraft_update > /tmp/cron.out

# TEST
* * * * * root env > /tmp/env.out
```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/419548/how-to-set-up-a-root-cron-job-properly)

Comment: You *do* need a user field (`root` by default) in the system-wide `/etc/crontab` file (which is what the OP appears to be using) - please see the `EXAMPLE SYSTEM CRON FILE` section of `man 5 crontab`

Comment: @steeldriver Sorry, thought 'sudo crontab -e' edited that by default.

Comment: I was editing `/etc/crontab` directly as root. Now that you mention it, I did read somewhere that using `crontab -e` was better, I'll try that. So `crontab -e` does **not** edit `/etc/crontab`? What file does it manipulate then?

Comment: @Willman `crontab -e` edits a file in the directory `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` named after the user, so `sudo crontab -e` edits `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root`. Note that each file is run with the permissions of its respective user.

Comment: Nevermind, this *is* working now, thanks! For some reason, the file that was supposed to be written every time my script runs wasn't being detected by my `watch -n 0.1` command on the dir.... But I confirmed a different way that it was working. Weird...