# Can't reboot ubuntu 18.04 using cron job

Tags: 18.04, cron

I'm trying to reboot my server with cron job. I added below line

```
35 14 * * * root shutdown -r now
```

But nothing happens. I shared journalctl log at below

```
>Feb 15 14:35:01 example CRON[2840]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
>Feb 15 14:35:01 example CRON[2848]: (root) CMD (root /sbin/shutdown -r now)
>Feb 15 14:35:01 example CRON[2840]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Note: I tried both `shutdown` and `/sbin/shutdown`. But still same.

How do I fix this ?

Comment: *"added below line"* where? it looks like you are mixing up the system-wide `/etc/crontab` and regular user-crontab formats

Comment: I opened crontab with  `crontab -e` then added above line, then I restart the service with `systemctl restart cron` @steeldriver

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/931090/178692

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit a cronjob of the root user.

1. `sudo -i`
2. `crontab -e`
3. Edit cronjob as needed:

   ```
   35 14 * * * root shutdown -r now
   ```

Work!

Answer (score 0):

Go to the directory /etc/cron.d, Take a copy of one of the existing files and change the job to:

35 14 * * * root systemctl isolate reboot.target