# Why I am seeing different content in crontab -e and nano /etc/crontab

Tags: cron

I just start learning to use cron job. I've learned that cron jobs' setting and information are stored at `/etc/crontab` and  I come across this command `crontab -e`, when I execute it, I was prompted to choose an editor.

I was expecting to see same content from these 2 different approaches, but actually they are totally different. In the second approach, after I choose an editor, I notice I am actually editing a file under `/tmp/something`.

Why is that? And which one is the right way to set cron jobs?

My server is ubuntu 14.04 and I have webmin/virtualmin installed, I am not sure if they play any part in this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/etc/crontab` is *root's* `crontab`. `crontab -e` edits the `crontab` for the *current user*.

Comment: where to find current user's crontab file?

Comment: Actually, there's a process to create it - http://askubuntu.com/questions/216692/where-is-the-user-crontab-stored