# How to locate the cron file entry for a scheduled task?

Tags: cron

I have an old Ubuntu system. `crontab -l` shows that a particular job is running every 30 minutes:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
30 * * * * ~/scripts/ferc.sh
```

However, I am unable to find this line in `/etc/crontab` or any file in all of the `/etc/cron.*` folders.

Where else can cron configuration be kept?

Comment: User crontabs [are on `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USER`](https://askubuntu.com/a/216711/349837), but you should edit it with `crontab -e`

Comment: Thanks. That's the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User crontabs are on [`/var/spool/cron/crontabs/$USER`](https://askubuntu.com/a/216711/349837)

For all cron jobs that should be executed under a user's account, [you should use `crontab -e`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/119491/209677).

> The `-e` option is used to edit the current crontab using the editor specified by the `VISUAL` or `EDITOR` environment variables.  After you exit from the  editor,  the  modified  crontab will  be installed automatically. If neither of the environment variables is defined, then the default editor `/usr/bin/editor` is used.

More at [`cron`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man3/cron.3tcl.html) and [`crontab`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/crontab.1.html) man pages.

Change the default editor with [`sudo update-alternatives --config editor`](https://askubuntu.com/a/913616/349837). For just one time you can run for e.g. `EDITOR=vim crontab -e`.