# crontab -e. Added entries but no /etc/crontab

Tags: cron, editor

I did edit /etc/crontab using corntab -e.

I have only one entry
[image]

After save contab is not created despite the message.

[image]

To be honest I have no idea what to do. I simply want to create a simple daily job.

Second question. How can I change the editor for `crontab -e`?

Comment: `crontab -e` doesn't edit the system-wide `/etc/crontab` file - it edits user-specific files in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`. Do you see your changes if you type `crontab -l`?

Comment: Change editor with `sudo select-editor`

Comment: @codlord without the `sudo`. Then the preference is set for the current user only. However, that is a different question and does not belong in this question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the user crontab stored?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/216692/where-is-the-user-crontab-stored)

Comment: crontab -l shows me my crontab. Will it run even if I am not logged in?

Comment: It will run when the computer is switched on, your login is not necessary, but your `backupshare` ***might*** not be mounted which would cause the command to fail.

Comment: It is my local server running gitlab. Need to delete gitlab backup files :)(. One week backup is enough for me

Comment: @pLumo is there any way to see if my command was executed correctly?

Comment: check https://askubuntu.com/questions/56683/where-is-the-cron-crontab-log

Comment: @steeldriver You should probably post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `crontab -e` does not edit the system-wide crontab file `/etc/crontab`, it edits a user-specific file in `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` . The editor used may be changed using the `EDITOR` or `VISUAL` environment variable ex.

```
EDITOR=/bin/nano crontab -e
```

You can confirm that you changes have installed by listing the crontab file, using `crontab -l` .

If you want to place your job in `/etc/crontab` instead, you would edit it like any other system file ex.

```
sudoedit /etc/crontab
```

or (to use the `nano` editor explicitly)

```
sudo nano /etc/crontab
```

but remember that the format of this file is slightly different - in particular, because the file is not user-specific it requires an additional (sixth) field containing the username under which to run each job.